# How to access vnc over HTTP using SSH Tunnel?

Tags: debian, ssh-tunneling, vnc, aws, tightvnc

I have an AWS Debian9 EC2 instance running, I have set up TightVNC and can access the server via a VNC client. I've allowed access to ports 5900, 5901, 22, 80 and 443 via the security groups in AWS.

I run the VNC server with the following:

```
vncserver :1 -geometry 1024x768 -depth 16
```

And open the SSH tunnel using the following command:

```
ssh -L 5901:127.0.0.1:5901 -C -N -l admin <ip.address.of.server>
```

This seems to work fine as when I load up localhost:5901 in the browser I get the following:

```
RFB 003.008
```

What am I missing? I've been trying to follow [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-debian-9) which worked all the way through to the SSH tunnel section where it seems to just work.

How do I set up tightVNC on Debian9 to display in the browser via an SSH tunnel?

Answer (score 0):

VNC needs a client program, it’s typically not accessed through a browser. Although there may be some browser plugins or extensions available, I didn’t check.

Install **TightVNC *client*** on your laptop and open `localhost:1` in it (that `:1` means first VNC display on the remote host which defaults to port `5901`). It will connect to port 5901 locally and will be forwarded to the server over ssh.